# Microsoft edge tablet mode media query max width always the "landscape" width

Tags: media-queries, tablet, microsoft-edge

In Edge, on a Surface Pro 2 in tablet mode, the max-width always seems to be the "natural landscape" width.  So when viewing pages in portrait, the media queries for the larger width are active.  Is this a bug or a feature, and if feature is there something I can do to code around it?

When in desktop mode it works properly.